# Developing Rice Milling Module In ERP

Tags: module, software-design, erp, adempiere

I want to develop a Rice manufacturing module in our erp (Adempiere) below are our details

*We purchase Rice From Vendor and then send these rice for milling process 
*After Milling Process our rice is divided in many sub product for eg 
  1-Fine Rice which is almost 70-80 %
  2-B1 Rice which is the broken rice its ratio is 10-20 %
  3-B2 Rice which is the rice collect during sweeping process in the mill its ratio is 5%

How I can Manage Such Scenario in my erp or refer me some erp where such scenario is implemented

Comment: The details are too short. Do you need a manufacturing automation system? You can relay on ADempiere for the basic trading needs.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is a production or manufacturing module. If you are using ADempiere you can implement the Manufacturing Module from Libero.

Basically what you do is define your production plan based on a bill of materials (Your input), a formula and your final products (output).

In your example, your input will be the Rice. Then you have your formula, 80% goes to 1-Fine and so on and your output will be the produced 1-Fine, 2-B1 and 3-B2. The module will process and produce and make the inventory movements to update the existences (-Rice, +1-Fine, +2-B1, +3-B2).

You can read a lot more here
[Step by Step Guide to Adempiere Manufacturing](http://www.adempiere.com/A_Step_by_Step_Guide_to_Libero_Manufacturing)

HIH

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you can use the Libero manufacturing business process, however I believe that you can use the much simpler production module to set up you production process. You just need to set up the formula and run prodcution batches as required.

Regards